# React component props not updating on Enzyme simulate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a following react component that displays Counter. There is a parent component `Counters` which holds the state of all the counter counts.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="btn">{this.props.counter.count}</span>
        <button
           onClick={ () => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter.id) }
          className="incr btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        >
          increment
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

`onIncrement` callback increments the counter.count by 1. I tried to test button click event using `enzyme`

```
it('increment button click', () => {
    const demoCounter = {id: 1, count: 0};
    const component = shallow( < Counter counter={demoCounter} onIncrement={(count) => 1} /> );
    component.find('button.incr').simulate('click');
    const spanText = component.find('span').text();

    expect(spanText).toBe('1');
});
```

but the counter is not getting incremented. Thus, `expect(spanText).toBe('1');` fails as count is still 0.
Did I miss anything?

I am fairly new to react and enzyme. Please suggest if my approach is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

After the click simulation on your component, you need it to "update", in order for it to follow the necessary steps of react lifecycle.

What you miss, is just the line `component.update()`, right after the `simulate('click')`.

So your test should look like the following:

```js
it('should increment counter by 1 on button click', () => {
  const demoCounter = {id: 1, count: 0};
  const component = shallow(<Counter counter={demoCounter} onIncrement={(count) => 1} />);
  component.find('button.incr').simulate('click');
  component.update(); // <--- Add this line here

  const spanText = component.find('span').text();

  expect(spanText).toBe('1');
});
```